# Indy TIdCmdTcpClient debug time losing commands

Tags: delphi, logging, command, delphi-xe2, indy

I have an application with TIdCmdTcpClient and command handlers.

What happens is that sometimes if successive calls to the same command handler (same cmd) arrive from the server (a C external app) the command hanlder event does not trigger, even though I can see in the log that the cmd has arrived correctly. The commands end with an LF.

I put a breakpoint in the command hanlder event and efectively it does not stop there when it should. The cmd is in fact in the log (TIdLogEvent). This ocurrs randomly.

Any clue to this issue?

usgin XE2 with its Indy components.

Definition for the command handler :

```
procedure TdmConn.tcpChannelCommandHandlers9Command(ASender: TIdCommand) { TR };
var
  Idx, Slot: Integer;
  TheTourn: TTourn;
begin
  Slot := StrToInt(ASender.Params[0]);
  Idx := TournBySlot(Slot);

  if Idx > -1 then
    TheTourn := TournList[Idx]
  else
    TheTourn := nil;

  if ASender.Params[2] = 'info' then
  begin
    if ASender.Params[3] = 'rules' then
      if Client.Accepted then
        tcpChannel.IOHandler.Write('UPBAL ALL' + LF);
    TSyncTRInfo.SyncTRInfo(TheTourn, ASender.Params.Text, frmLobby);
  end;

  if ASender.Params[2] = 'ok' then
  begin
    TSyncTROk.SyncTROk(TheTourn, ASender.Params.Text, frmLobby);
  end;

  if ASender.Params[2] = 'assign' then
  begin
    TSyncTR.SyncTR(TheTourn, ASender.Params.Text, frmLobby);
  end;

  if ASender.Params[2] = 'leave' then
  begin
    TSyncTR.SyncTR(TheTourn, ASender.Params.Text, frmLobby);
  end;
    end;
```

Definition for the TIdSync class:

```
  TSyncTR = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FTourn: TTourn;
    FParams: string;
    Flobby: TfrmLobby;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ATourn: TTourn; AParams: string; Alobby: TfrmLobby); reintroduce;
    class procedure SyncTR(ATourn: TTourn; AParams: string; Alobby: TfrmLobby);
  end;

procedure TSyncTR.DoSynchronize;
var
  I, Idx, RoomID, RoomSlot: Integer;
  slParams: TStringList;
  RoomForm: TfrmRoom;
begin
  inherited;
  slParams := TStringList.Create;
  try
    slParams.Text := FParams;
    if slParams[2] = 'assign' then // TR 0 tournament assign table 3748 seat 0
    begin
      RoomID := StrToIntDef(FTourn.Rooms.Values[slParams[4]], -1);
      CreateRoomItem(RoomID, '', '', '', '', FTourn);
      Client.Seat := StrToInt(slParams[6]);
    end;

    if slParams[2] = 'leave' then // TR 0 tournament leave table 3654
    begin
      RoomID := StrToIntDef(FTourn.Rooms.Values[slParams[4]], -1);
      if RoomID > -1 then
      begin
        Idx := RoomByID(RoomID);
        if Idx > -1 then
        begin
          DelPlyr(Client.UserName, Client.Seat, RoomList.Items[Idx]);
          RoomSlot := RoomList.Items[Idx].Slot;
          dmConn.SendChannel('JOIN ' + IntToStr(RoomSlot) + ' poker ' + IntToStr(RoomID));
        end
        else // in case GSLOTFREED
        begin
          for I := 0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do // room item may have been freed
          begin
            if Application.Components[I] is TfrmRoom then
            begin
              RoomForm := TfrmRoom(Application.Components[I]);
              if (RoomForm.RoomData.TournSlot = FTourn.Slot) then
              begin
                CreateRoomItem(RoomID, '', '', '', '', FTourn, RoomForm);
                dmConn.SendChannel('JOIN ' + IntToStr(RoomForm.RoomData.Slot) + ' poker ' + IntToStr(RoomID));
              end;
            end;
          end; { }
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    slParams.Free;
  end;
    end;
```

This a chunk of the log

```
Revd : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 GR 0 poker rejoin 77<LF>GR 0 poker rejoin 79<LF>GR 0 poker rejoin 80<LF>GR 0 poker rejoin 82<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 33406<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103452<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103453<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103483<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103490<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103491<LF>CLIENTINFO screenname= levelname= stagename= levelnumber=0 userpoints=-1<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 33406<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103452<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103453<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103483<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103490<LF>GR 0 tournament rejoin 103491<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 TOURNJOIN 0 33406<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 TOURNJOIN 1 103452<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 TOURNJOIN 2 103453<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 TOURNJOIN 3 103483<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 TOURNJOIN 4 103490<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 TOURNJOIN 5 103491<LF>
Revd : 28/05/2013 11:32:24 BALANCE FUN=38440 TRN=30000 USD=27388 PTS=4008560<LF>
Revd : 28/05/2013 11:32:25 GR 0 poker rejoin 77<LF>GR 0 poker rejoin 79<LF>GR 0 poker rejoin 80<LF>GR 0 poker rejoin 82<LF>TR 0 tournament ok rejoin 33406<LF>TR 0 tournament info stats players_registered=2 players_playing=2 tables_created=1 cur_time=1369733542 reg_open=1360188060 reg_close=1360274459 dereg_close=1360274459 start=1360274460 started=0<LF>TR 0 tournament info rules tournament=8 currency=USD buyin=25 fee=10 chips=100000 addon_cost=0 addon_chips=0 addon_count=0 rebuys=0 insurance=0 reserved=0 max_players=10 min_players=8 reserved=0 reserved_left=0 can_register=0 type=GS max_bet=0 no_restrict=1 min_buyin=6000 deck=1 pot_limit=0 rake=0 timer=8 max_buyin=20000 start=5 min_player=2 mod_bet=1 ante=100 num_decks=1 min_bet=100 max_player=10 small_blind=50 big_blind=100<LF>TR 0 tournament info tourn_name test 10<LF>TR 0 tournament info tourn_desc test 10<LF>TR 0 tournament info game Texas Holdem<LF>TR 0 tournament info break next=0 interval=3600 length=300<LF>TR 0 tournament info table 1 id=335 seats=2 room=82<LF>TR 0 tournament info player table=335 seat=0 chips=100000 username=Willix position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 0 tournament info player table=335 seat=9 chips=100000 username=josefm position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 0 tournament info you registered=1 chips=100000 rebuys=0 addons=0<LF>TR 0 tournament info pot total=50 remaining=50<LF>TR 0 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 0 tournament
Revd : 28/05/2013 11:32:25  tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 0 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 0 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 0 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 0 tournament info prize total 0<LF>TR 0 tournament assign table 335 seat 0<LF>TRB 0 tournament player assign Willix table 335 seat 0<LF>TR 1 tournament ok rejoin 103452<LF>TR 1 tournament info stats players_registered=2 players_playing=2 tables_created=1 cur_time=1369733542 reg_open=1369643700 reg_close=1369730099 dereg_close=1369730099 start=1369730100 started=1369730100<LF>TR 1 tournament info rules tournament=2 currency=USD buyin=50 fee=10 chips=200000 addon_cost=0 addon_chips=0 addon_count=0 rebuys=0 insurance=0 reserved=0 max_players=0 min_players=2 reserved=0 reserved_left=0 can_register=0 type=WM max_bet=0 no_restrict=1 min_buyin=12000 deck=1 pot_limit=0 rake=0 timer=8 max_buyin=40000 start=5 min_player=2 mod_bet=1 ante=200 num_decks=1 min_bet=200 max_player=10 small_blind=100 big_blind=200<LF>TR 1 tournament info tourn_name $0.60 NL Holdem<LF>TR 1 tournament info tourn_desc Only $0.60 to enter! 2.000 chip stack. Good luck!<LF>TR 1 tournament info game Texas Holdem<LF>TR 1 tournament info break next=158 interval=3600 length=300<LF>TR 1 tournament info table 1 id=3141 seats=2 room=80<LF>TR 1 tournament info player table=3141 seat=0 chips=213500 username=josefm position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 1 tournament info player table=3141 seat=3 chips=186500 username=Willix position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 1 tournament info you registered=1 chips=186500 rebuys=0 addons=0<LF>TR 1 tournament info pot total=100 remaining=100<LF>TR 1 tournament payout start<LF>TR 1 tournament payout entry start=1 end=1 cut=10000<LF>TR 1 tournament payout end<LF>TR 1 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 1 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 1 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 1 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 1 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1 time=159 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 1 tournament info prize total 0<LF>TR 1 tournament assign table 3141 seat 3<LF>TRB 1 tournament player assign Willix table 3141 seat 3<LF>TR 2 tournament ok rejoin 103453<LF>TR 2 tournament info stats players_registered=2 players_playing=2 tables_created=1 cur_time=1369733542 reg_open=1369643700 reg_close=1369730099 dereg_close=1369730099 start=1369730100 started=1369730100<LF>TR 2 tournament info rules tournament=4 currency=USD buyin=100 fee=10 chips=100000 addon_cost=0 addon_chips=0 addon_count=0 rebuys=0 insurance=0 reserved=0 max_players=0 min_players=2 reserved=0 reserved_left=0 can_register=0 type=WM max_bet=0 no_restrict=0 min_buyin=6000 deck=1 pot_limit=1 rake=1 timer=15 max_buyin=20000 hi_lo=0 start=5 min_player=2 mod_bet=1 ante=100 num_decks=1 min_bet=100 max_player=10 small_blind=50 big_blind=100<LF>TR 2 tournament info tourn_name $1.10 NL Omaha<LF>TR 2 tournament info tourn_desc Payouts are based on the number of entrants. Final payouts will be shown after registration closes<LF>TR 2 tournament info game Omaha<LF>TR 2 tournament info break next=158 interval=3600 length=300<LF>TR 2 tournament info table 1 id=3142 seats=2 room=79<LF>TR 2 tournament info player table=3142 seat=0 chips=108550 username=josefm position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 2 tournament info player table=3142 seat=8 chips=91450 username=Willix position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 2 tournament info you registered=1 chips=91450 rebuys=0 addons=0<LF>TR 2 tournament info pot total=200 remaining=200<LF>TR 2 tournament payout start<LF>TR 2 tournament payout entry start=1 end=1 cut=10000<LF>TR 2 tournament payout end<LF>TR 2 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 2 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 2 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 2 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 2 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1 time=159 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 2 tournament info prize total 0<LF>TR 2 tournament assign table 3142 seat 8<LF>TRB 2 tournament player assign Willix table 3142 seat 8<LF>TR 3 tournament ok rejoin 103483<LF>TR 3 tournament info stats players_registered=5 players_playing=2 tables_created=1 cur_time=1369733542 reg_open=1369646100 reg_close=1369732499 dereg_close=1369732499 start=1369732500 started=1369732501<LF>TR 3 tournament info rules tournament=2 currency=USD buyin=50 fee=10 chips=200000 addon_cost=0 addon_chips=0 addon_count=0 rebuys=0 insurance=0 reserved=0 max_players=0 min_players=2 reserved=0 reserved_left=0 can_register=0 type=WM max_bet=0 no_restrict=1 min_buyin=12000 deck=1 pot_limit=0 rake=0 timer=8 max_buyin=40000 start=5 min_player=2 mod_bet=1 ante=200 num_decks=1 min_bet=200 max_player=10 small_blind=100 big_blind=200<LF>TR 3 tournament info tourn_name $0.60 NL Holdem<LF>TR 3 tournament info tourn_desc Only $0.60 to enter! 2.000 chip stack. Good luck!<LF>TR 3 tournament info game Texas Holdem<LF>TR 3 tournament info break next=2559 interval=3600 length=300<LF>TR 3 tournament info table 1 id=3148 seats=2 room=77<LF>TR 3 tournament info player table=3148 seat=0 chips=804000 username=Willix position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 3 tournament info player table=3148 seat=9 chips=196000 username=twoaces position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 3 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=josefm position=5 winnings=0<LF>TR 3 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=josefm6 position=4 winnings=0<LF>TR 3 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=willifras12 position=3 winnings=0<LF>TR 3 tournament info you registered=1 chips=804000 rebuys=0 addons=0<LF>TR 3 tournament info pot total=250 remaining=250<LF>TR 3 tournament payout start<LF>TR 3 tournament payout entry start=1 end=1 cut=10000<LF>TR 3 tournament payout end<LF>TR 3 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 3 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 3 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 3 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 3 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1 time=159 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 3 tournament info prize total 0<LF>TR 3 tournament assign table 3148 seat 0<LF>TRB 3 tournament player assign Willix table 3148 seat 0<LF>TR 4 tournament ok rejoin 103490<LF>TR 4 tournament info stats players_registered=9 players_playing=3 tables_created=1 cur_time=1369733542 reg_open=1369646701 reg_close=1369733100 dereg_close=1369733100 start=1369733101 started=1369733100<LF>TR 4 tournament info rules tournament=2 currency=USD buyin=50 fee=10 chips=200000 addon_cost=0 addon_chips=0 addon_count=0 rebuys=0 insurance=0 reserved=0 max_players=0 min_players=2 reserved=0 reserved_left=0 can_register=0 type=WM max_bet=0 no_restrict=1 min_buyin=12000 deck=1 pot_limit=0 rake=0 timer=8 max_buyin=40000 start=5 min_player=2 mod_bet=1 ante=200 num_decks=1 min_bet=200 max_player=10 small_blind=100 big_blind=200<LF>TR 4 tournament info tourn_name $0.60 NL Holdem<LF>TR 4 tournament info tourn_desc Only $0.60 to enter! 2.000 chip stack. Good luck!<LF>TR 4 tournament info game Texas Holdem<LF>TR 4 tournament info break next=3158 interval=3600 length=300<LF>TR 4 tournament info table 1 id=3151 seats=3 room=76<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=3151 seat=1 chips=298800 username=pokerqueen2 position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=3151 seat=5 chips=198700 username=josefm position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=3151 seat=8 chips=1302500 username=josefm6 position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=willifras12 position=4 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=pokerwin position=5 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=rocococo position=8 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=azucar position=6 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=twoaces positio
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:25 TOURNINFO 103500<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:25 UPBAL ALL<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:25 JOIN 0 poker 82<LF>
Sent : 28/05/2013 11:32:25 CLIENT 0 canbuy<LF>
Revd : 28/05/2013 11:32:25 n=9 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=Willix position=7 winnings=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info you registered=1 chips=0 rebuys=0 addons=0<LF>TR 4 tournament info pot total=450 remaining=450<LF>TR 4 tournament payout start<LF>TR 4 tournament payout entry start=1 end=1 cut=10000<LF>TR 4 tournament payout end<LF>TR 4 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 4 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 4 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 4 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 4 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1 time=158 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 4 tournament info prize total 0<LF>TR 5 tournament ok rejoin 103491<LF>TR 5 tournament info stats players_registered=9 players_playing=2 tables_created=1 cur_time=1369733542 reg_open=1369646521 reg_close=1369732920 dereg_close=1369732920 start=1369732921 started=1369732920<LF>TR 5 tournament info rules tournament=1 currency=USD buyin=25 fee=10 chips=100000 addon_cost=0 addon_chips=0 addon_count=0 rebuys=0 insurance=0 reserved=0 max_players=0 min_players=8 reserved=0 reserved_left=0 can_register=0 type=WM max_bet=0 no_restrict=1 min_buyin=6000 deck=1 pot_limit=0 rake=0 timer=8 max_buyin=20000 start=5 min_player=2 mod_bet=1 ante=100 num_decks=1 min_bet=100 max_player=10 small_blind=50 big_blind=100<LF>TR 5 tournament info tourn_name $0.35 NL Holdem<LF>TR 5 tournament info tourn_desc Only $0.35 to enter! 1.000 chip stack. Good luck!<LF>TR 5 tournament info game Texas Holdem<LF>TR 5 tournament info break next=2978 interval=3600 length=300<LF>TR 5 tournament info table 1 id=3150 seats=2 room=75<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=3150 seat=0 chips=495500 username=pokerwin position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=3150 seat=7 chips=404500 username=josefm6 position=0 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=pokerqueen2 position=8 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=rocococo position=7 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=josefm position=4 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=azucar position=9 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=willifras12 position=6 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=twoaces position=3 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info player table=0 seat=-1 chips=0 username=Willix position=5 winnings=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info you registered=1 chips=0 rebuys=0 addons=0<LF>TR 5 tournament info pot total=225 remaining=225<LF>TR 5 tournament payout start<LF>TR 5 tournament payout entry start=1 end=1 cut=10000<LF>TR 5 tournament payout end<LF>TR 5 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 5 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 5 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 5 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 5 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1 time=278 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TR 5 tournament info prize total 0<LF>TRB 5 tournament chips pokerwin 495200<LF>TRB 5 tournament chips josefm6 404800<LF>TRB 5 tournament tourn expiry late_reg matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TRB 5 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TRB 5 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TRB 5 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>TRB 5 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1 time=278 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1<LF>BALANCE FUN=38440 TRN=30000 USD=27388 PTS=4008560<LF>
```

Comment: Please show the actual log, and the actual CommandHandler definition. Did you verify that the first command's event is actually exiting correctly, not deadlocking? The only way the second event would not trigger is if either the received data is malformed, or the calling thread is blocked from reading the second command.

Comment: There is no deadlocking, the event is exiting correctly. I suspect the culprit is the timing and the length of the data. It seems the client buffer cannot process all the data so fast. Because this does not happen if it is only one (large) command that the client receives. It happens only when the same (large) command is sent more than twice. It does not happen al the time but majority of times. It seems the server sometimes is sending more data than the client can process.

Comment: TR 1 tournament tourn expiry addon matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1
TR 1 tournament tourn expiry rebuy matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1
TR 1 tournament tourn expiry hand_wait matched=-1 time=-1 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1
TR 1 tournament tourn expiry cur_round matched=1
Send : 12:06:12:885 JOIN 0 poker 77
Send : 12:06:12:886 CLIENT 0 canbuy
Recv : 12:06:13:212  time=51 rounds=-1 hands=-1 players=-1
TR 1 tournament info prize total 0
TR 2 tournament ok rejoin 103508

Comment: This is not a timing-related or size-related issue, since Indy uses blocking sockets and buffered reading. I asked for your CommandHandler definition. I assume `TR` is your command that is failing? Are there line breaks between the commands? Putting the log in comments is useless, please attach the log to your original question.

Comment: I updated my post but have not find how to attach the file, so I included only a portion of the log. By the way, there is no deadlock nor exceptions when this ocurrs..

Comment: Ths skip ocurrs under this condition (if slParams[2] = 'assign' then) where it should stop but does not stop sometimes. Ocurrs in other commands as well..

Comment: You say that your commands are terminated by LFs, but there are no LFs in your log (TIdLog... logs them as `<LF>` by default), which would account for the symptoms you describe.  Can you provide an actual capture of the raw data from the socket itself, such as from Wireshark, to verify?

Comment: I have changed the log generated in the OnReceive using ABuffer variable event by its equivalent in the OnReceived using AText and AData variables. In fact i use TIdLogEvent for this. Hope it is clarifying..

Comment: Thnx for all, the issue is now solved, it was a coding error of mine. Thnkx everyone..